# How to display different different data form in Json response?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

**I'm successfully got responded from my API , also able to display `Status` and `Message` in my App.
But How to display `Name` & `EncUserId` as it is inside `UserData`
Here is my JSON response in Postman**

```
{
"Status": "1",
"Message": "You are Logged in successfully",
"UserData": {
    "Name": "qwerty@gmail.com",
    "EncUserId": "GO9gj3aSUKCpxE3AMSbh/A=="
    }
}
```

**Im Displaying my Json response in my App in this format**

```
    Text("Status: ${widget.response.status}"),
    Text("Message: ${widget.response.message}"),
```

Here is API model

```
class ApiResponse {
ApiResponse({
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    required this.userData,
});

String status;
String message;
UserData? userData; 

factory ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ApiResponse(
    status: json["Status"],
    message: json["Message"],
   
     userData: json["UserData"] == null? null:UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    );


}

class UserData {
    UserData({
        required this.name,
        required this.encUserId,
    });

String name;
String encUserId;

    factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserData(
        name: json["Name"],
        encUserId: json["EncUserId"],
    );

}
```

Comment: you can also access UserData like Message/status -> Text("Name: ${widget.response.UserData.Name}"). try this or not?

Comment: Its showing error under `UserData` ==> `The getter 'UserData' isn't defined for the type 'ApiResponse'.`  do I have to do something in my model class?

Comment: 1st get only UserData and check error occur or not? if not then get/fetch inside UserData array data. Text("name: ${widget.response.userData.name}");

Comment: its working by putting Null checker! `Text("Name: ${widget.response.userData!.name}"),` thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
Text("name: ${widget.response.userData.name}"),
Text("encUserId: ${widget.response.userData.encUserId}")
```

Comment: yeah also I have to add the Null checker `Text("Name: ${widget.response.userData!.name}"),`